# Replace XML-element with LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I would like to solve the following problem *using LINQ to XML*, if possible. Using LINQ to XML might not be the suitable way to solve a problem like this? If not, what is the best technique to use? All elements like this:

```
<Name>XXX</Name>
```

sholud be replaced with:

```
<Attribute name="Name">XXX</Attribute>
```

in the following XML?

```
  <Object type="SignalGroup">
    <Name>General</Name>
    <Object type="Signal">
      <Name>Input</Name>
      <Attribute name="Description">This is a public object.</Attribute>
    </Object>
    <Object type="Signal">
      <Name>PublicName</Name>
      <Attribute name="ToolTitle">Public name</Attribute>
      <Attribute name="Description">This is a public object.</Attribute>
    </Object>
  </Object>
```

The desired result is:

```
  <Object type="SignalGroup">
    <Attribute name="Name">General</Attribute>
    <Object type="Signal">
      <Attribute name="Name">Input</Attribute>
      <Attribute name="Description">This is a public object.</Attribute>
    </Object>
    <Object type="Signal">
      <Attribute name="Name">PublicName</Attribute>
      <Attribute name="ToolTitle">Public name</Attribute>
      <Attribute name="Description">This is a public object.</Attribute>
    </Object>
  </Object>
```

Comment: LINQ is query language. It is designed for retrieving values from a data source, not modifying documents. While it is certainly possible using LINQ, it would hardly be efficient or clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to query all elements with the name `Name` and *either* rename that element and add the missing attribute, *or* replace them with an `Attribute` element that has the value of that element.

So either this:

```
foreach (var name in doc.Descendants("Name"))
{
    name.Name = "Attribute";
    name.Add(new XAttribute("name", "Name"));
}
```

Or this. Note the `ToList` is required here as replacing the element would break the enumeration as you'll have removed the current element from the document.

```cs
foreach (var name in doc.Descendants("Name").ToList())
{
    var attr = new XElement("Attribute",
        new XAttribute("name", "Name"), name.Value);
    name.ReplaceWith(attr);
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4hFPcb) for a demo.